# Prove, if $z=z_0$ is a zero of order $n$ of $f(z)$, then it is a zero of order $2n$ of $(f(z))^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Where would you start with this proof. I understand that if $z=z_0$ is a zero of order $n$ of $f(z)$, then it is a zero of order $mn$ of $(f(z))^m$ but do not know how to go about in proving this.

Comment: "Where would you start with this proof[?]" From the **definition** of the order of a zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start like this: if $z_0$ is a zero of otder $n$ of $f$, then, near $z_0$, $f(z)$ can be written as $(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ where $g$ is analytic and $g(z_0)\neq0$. (I am assuming that $f$ is analytic.)

Comment: how would you carry on this proof?

Comment: @user544158 If $f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$, what do you deduce about $f^2(z)$?

Comment: the whole function be squared leaving us with (z-z_0)^2n g(z)^2. However I cannot see how this will give me the order of 2n?

Comment: @user544158 ... and $g(z_0)^2$ is still non-zero. That is what gives you the order.

Comment: is it not (z-z_0)^2n in which you would look at for the order?

Comment: @user544158 Sure. The presence of $(z-z_0)^{2n}$ assures that the order is *at least* $2n$. And the fact that $g^2(z_0)\neq0$ assures then that it is *exactly* $2n$.

Comment: so would it be correct to say that: if z=z_0 is a zero of order n, then it can be represented as f(z)-(z-z_0)^n g(z) where g(z) is analytic at z=z_0 and g(z) is non-zero. Therefore we attain that (f(z))^2 = (z-z^0)^2n g(z)^2 hence z_o must be a zero of order 2n as g(z)^2 remains analytic at z=z_0 and is non zero

Comment: @user544158 Yes, that would be correct.